# Remove unsent attributes from Microsoft Active Directory

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, apache-camel

I create users in Microsoft Active Directory.

Scenario:
 1. Create user to AD with mail, samaccountname, sn, givenname
 2. Update the same user and provide only mail, samaccountname, sn. I want the givenname to be deleted from the AD for this user. However it stays. It will be deleted if I send the attribute with empty value.
I do not know what optional attributes were provided with previous requests, so I cannot send them.

I am Java app that writes to AD using apache camel using javax.naming

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/directory/Attributes.html#remove(java.lang.String)) method:

```
attributes.remove("mail");
```

Comment: Hi Gabriel. Thanks for your reply. As I mentioned in my question, I do not know what attributes the user was created with on the previous request. Isnt it just possible to write to AD what I send in the current request and delete everything else. For example, the user might have nickname=X in the first request and does not have it in the second. However, I do not know that nickname was provided on the first request. And I cannot remove all possible attributes as I do not know which exactly are they.

Comment: No, there is no way to tell it to remove all attributes. You need to tell it specifically which ones you want to remove.

Comment: That is really inconvenient. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Well, I guess you could use [`getAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/directory/Attributes.html#getAll()) to find all the attributes with values, then you can push those back into `remove()`. But it will give you *every attribute* with a value, including many that cannot be removed (like `sAMAccountName`, `objectSid`, etc.)

Comment: Yes, I wanted to avoid this option as it will make an extra call + attribute merge for every user. If I have 200k users it might be a significant problem. If there is no other options seems like I have to stick to it. Thank you for the help!